# MySql search query fails to return rows containing %20 inside

Tags: mysql, database, operators, query-string

I have a problem with my database queries. When I try to pull rows where spaces were converted to %20 earlier, the query returns null. I have tested other rows which works fine, why is this problem occurring?  Do I need to remove the %20's manually from each row to get it to working?

Thanks!

[image: database screenshot]

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LIKES= '$_GET[imgname]' ";

//Creating resonse json array, with another array inside
$jsonResponse = array( "info" =>array() );

if($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

     $jsonRow = array(        

         'names'            =>      $row['USERNAME'],
         'userIds'          =>      $row['USERID']   

        );          

        //adding the $jsonRow array to the end of the "users" array as key/value
        array_push($jsonResponse["info"], $jsonRow);
    }   

}
    //encoding to json for the app
    echo json_encode($jsonResponse);



?>
```

Comment: Please post your table structure, and 5-10 rows of sample data and expected results. Without either of those, it's really hard to determine what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your SQL query to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LIKES= '".rawurlencode($_GET[imgname])."' ";
```

The `LIKES` column has image path encoded (space converted to `%20`). Therefore, `$_GET[imgname]` should be encoded to match the database record.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately the search query still returns null.

Comment: When I echo the result I get: Crush%20Coffee%20House%2Fhaselnut_late.jpg - the second space was morphed into: %2F, while ignoring the '/' I guess it is a reserved symbol. I have used: $strnew = str_replace('%2F', '/', $str); for a fix. Thanks!